# Visual studio code razor intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a razor/cshtml intellisense in visual studio code (1.18.1)?

How to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no Intellisense for Razor in vscode at this time:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/168#issuecomment-372085470